# How to specify the folder to create SQL database using dotnet ef

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I am using Dotnet EF Core, and have created migrations. When I run

```
dotnet ef database update
```

the database is created in my windows user folder.
My connection string is

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
     "ContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
 }
```

How do I get the database created in the project directory? (without having to have the full project pathname in the connection string) Using VS2015 I was able to include |DataDirectory| in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

These CLI commands can be run from the command line **by navigating to the project directory**

I think you are trying to run CLI commands directly from user profile hence database is created in your windows user folder.

First, navigate to your project directory by using simple dos commands (e.g. CD)

And then run these CLI commands-

```
dotnet ef [options] [command]
```

One of the option-
`-p|--project <PROJECT>`              The project to target (defaults to the project in the current directory). Can be a path to a project.json or a project directory.

For more information refer this link-
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef

See if this helps.

Comment: Tried this, but the database is always created in my windows user folder regardless of where I run dotnet from